# LD_LIBRARY_PATH vs LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: gcc, g++, ld

I'm building a simple C++ program and I want to temporarily substitute a system supplied shared library with a more recent version of it, for development and testing.

I tried setting the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable but the linker (ld) failed with:

> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lyaml-cpp

I expected that to work because according to the ld man page:

> The linker uses the following search
>   paths to locate required shared
>   libraries:  ... For a native linker, 
>   the contents of the environment variable
>   "LD_LIBRARY_PATH"...

I then tried setting the LIBRARY_PATH, and that worked.

According to the GCC manual:

> The value of
>   LIBRARY_PATH is a colon-separated list
>   of directories, much like PATH. When
>   configured as a native compiler, GCC
>   tries the directories thus specified
>   when searching for special linker
>   files, if it can't find them using
>   GCC_EXEC_PREFIX. Linking using GCC
>   also uses these directories when
>   searching for ordinary libraries for
>   the -l option (but directories
>   specified with -L come first).

As the (GCC) manual suggests, LIBRARY_PATH works because I link with GCC.

But..

- Since I link with gcc why ld is
  being called, as the error message
  suggests?
- What's the point of
  having two variables serving the same
  purpose? Are there any other
  differences?

Comment: N.B. the text you quoted about _search the contents of the environment variable "LD_LIBRARY_PATH"_ was shown out of context. It's under the description of the `-rpath-link` option, which is related to finding shared libs that are **dependencies** of the shared libs you're linking to explicitly (to check that they satisfy any undefined refs in the ones you're linking to). The rpath-link dirs are **not** used to find the libs you're linking to explicitly, `ld` only uses the dirs named with the `-L` option for that (and GCC converts the contents of `LIBRARY_PATH` into `-L` options for `ld`).

Answer (score 274, accepted):

`LIBRARY_PATH` is used by gcc before compilation to search directories containing static and shared libraries that need to be linked to your program.

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is used by your program to search directories containing *shared* libraries after it has been successfully compiled and linked.

EDIT:
As pointed below, your libraries can be static or shared. If it is static then the code is copied over into your program and you don't need to search for the library after your program is compiled and linked. If your library is shared then it needs to be dynamically linked to your program and that's when `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` comes into play.

Comment: And of course LD_LIBRARY_PATH only makes sense with dynamic libraries

Comment: My point is that if I were to use ld for linking (directly),
then, according to the ld manual, LD_LIBRARY_PATH would have
been used to search for directories containing the libraries
that need to be linked to my program. I must be missing something here..

Comment: unless you invoke ld yourself and combine the object files with the libraries, it will 'inherit' the path that gcc passes to it. You can override the standard gcc, with -Xlinker options.

Comment: Actually, `LIBRARY_PATH ` is used for searching directories containing static **AND** dynamic libraries, instead of only static libraries.

Comment: Yeah this is wrong - the difference is that `LIBRARY_PATH` is searched for libraries (static or dynamic) at *compile time* and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is searched for dynamic libraries at run time. Of course at run time you don't need to search for static libraries.

Comment: would be great to also mention LD_RUN_PATH, even though it is not in the question

Comment: @Timmmm that's wrong, too ;) ... it's searched at _link time_. Just because the _compiler driver_ is used to do the linker step, doesn't mean it's _compiling_.

Comment: Yes if you are being pedantic. Linking is part of the compilation process. "compile-time" usually means "when compiling and linking".

Answer (score 63):

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is searched when the program starts, `LIBRARY_PATH` is searched at link time.

caveat from [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4250624/ld-library-path-vs-library-path#comment37966883_4293671):

- When linking libraries with `ld` (instead of `gcc` or `g++`), the `LIBRARY_PATH` or `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variables are not read.
- When linking libraries with `gcc` or `g++`, the `LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable is read (see [documentation "`gcc` uses these directories when searching for ordinary libraries"](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Environment-Variables.html)).

Comment: Note: when linking libraries, `ld` by itself does not look for libraries in either `LIBRARY_PATH` or `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.  It's only when `gcc` invokes `ld` that `LIBRARY_PATH` becomes used.  (Learned this the hard way.)

Comment: @Rufflewind Interesting, but would have been even more if you had given any reference.

Comment: This view makes a distinction in the moment the libraries are searched for (link time versus run time) while @Naveen makes a distinction of the type of libraries that are searched for (static v dynamic). Are there two views effectively identical (dynamic : run time = static : link time) or are there important situations when this correspondence does not hold? I would guess that some knowledge about the dynamic libraries is needed also at compile time.

Comment: @Rufflewind Hi Rufflewind. I read the manual for `ld` and it says `ld` only search `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` when searching for dependencies of a shared library. If you just run `ld -lSOMETHING` it won't search those paths in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, indeed.

Answer (score 15):

> Since I link with gcc why ld is being called, as the error message suggests?

gcc calls ld internally when it is in linking mode.

Answer (score 0):

`LIBRARY_PATH` is used by linker (ld)

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is used by loader (ld.so)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).