# Linker not taking local (user) boost installation with g++

Tags: dynamic, boost, linker, g++

I want to have local installation (in my home-folder (Linux), say $HOME/boost) of the boost C++ libraries in addition to a system-wide installed default of the boost libs. I built them from sorce and that worked fine.

After that, I set the environment variables CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH to match the destination of the local installation, so both pointing to $HOME/boost/include and $HOME/boost/lib/, respectively.

In order to test that, I used the following code for testing the correct usage of CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH for the headers:

```
#include <boost/version.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
  std::cout << "Boost version: " << BOOST_LIB_VERSION << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Compiling it with  `g++ -o Test_boost_version test_boost_version.cpp` works as expected, reporting the expected (local) version. Having CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH empty gives me the boost-version of the default, system-wide installation. So far so good.

In order to test the linking, I used the following code (taken from the boost homepage:

```
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string line;
    boost::regex pat( "^Subject: (Re: |Aw: )*(.*)" );

    while (std::cin)
    {   
        std::getline(std::cin, line);
        boost::smatch matches;
        if (boost::regex_match(line, matches, pat))
            std::cout << matches[2] << std::endl;
    }   
}
```

and built it with  `g++ -o Test_boost_linking test_boost_linking.cpp -lboost_regex`.

Calling `ldd Test_boost_linking` however does NOT make use of the local installation (provided via LD_LIBRARY_PATH) but gives me: `libboost_regex.so.1.42.0 => /usr/lib/libboost_regex.so.1.42.0 (0x00007f9264612000)`

When I use `g++ -o Test_boost_linking test_boost_linking.cpp -lboost_regex -L$HOME/boost/lib`, ldd is reporting the correct library (`libboost_regex.so.1.50.0 => $HOME/boost/lib/libboost_regex.so.1.50.0 (0x00007f6947d2a000)`).

This is actually a problem for me since I want to set up my local environment such that a compilation will ignore the system-default boost installation and only use the local installation and I thought this is exactly what is achieved when setting the CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH, but for the latter, this seems not to hold true.

So how can I make sure that using `g++ -o Test_boost_linking test_boost_linking.cpp -lboost_regex` (without -L) uses the local libraries?

[EDIT] Thinking of it further, I am wondering IF it is actually *absolutely* mandatory to use "-L$HOME/boost/lib" in the command-line (using LDFLAGS as environment variable seems to have no effect, probably just in combination with a Makefile) when using libraries in a non-standard directory?? Is this the case?

(BTW I think this will hold true also for other libraries, not only boost...)

(I used: g++ (Debian 4.4.5-8) 4.4.5)

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the environment variable `LIBRARY_PATH` to let gcc know where to find the libraries at link time. `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` lets the program know where to find the dynamic libraries at runtime. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4250624/ld-library-path-vs-library-path) has more details. These links from "An Introduction to GCC" may also be useful: [Compilation options:Environment Variables](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_23.html) and [Shared and Static Libraries](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_25.html)

Comment: Thank you, that apparently did the trick! I had tried that variable before, but apparently had a mistake as I discarded it for some reason.