# Clang linker does not look into LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: c++, cmake, clang, ld

I am trying to build and link a C++, cmake-based project with clang (3.0). This project links to several libraries that are installed in a custom directory /my/dir/. This directory is included in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH and LIBRARY_PATH environment variables. Project builds and links fine with g++.

The link command generated and executed by cmake looks like the following:

```
/usr/bin/clang++ -O3 stuff.cpp.o -o stuff -rdynamic -lmylib
```

ld then complains with the following message:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmylib
```

The link command above runs fine whenever I manually add `-L/my/dir/`. Is there a way to link without specifying the `-L` flag?

Comment: [`LD_LIBRARY_PATH`](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html) is for loading libraries at startup, not for resolving link dependencies. Perhaps you want to use `LDFLAGS`?

Comment: Interesting. I use __g++__ and __clang++__ interchangeably with CMake but never had a similar problem. I simply use the `link_directories()` macro to define the library path.

Answer (score 9):

The `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable (and its various alternatives on other UNIX-based platforms) is used at *runtime*, not *link time*, to find libraries.

Using `-L` is the correct approach and cannot be avoided.

Note: A better approach under Linux (you don't specify your platform so I'm guessing) is to correctly configure a file in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/` and avoid using `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` altogether.

Comment: Note that I also defined the LIBRARY_PATH variable. As explained in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4250624/ld-library-path-vs-library-path this variable is what allows gcc to find the custom libraries. I am looking for something similar for clang.

Comment: @RégisB. Interesting; I've never used `LIBRARY_PATH`.  What's the issue with using `-L`?

Comment: The -L option requires a change in the cmake configuration, which is shared with my colleagues. I will now try going the /etc/ld.so.conf.d/ way.

Comment: @RégisB. The `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/` is *runtime* only as well; I mentioned it as it's a better approach than using `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`; it won't affect your build. Why not add a custom variable to the cmake config that each of you can set to specify additional libraries during linking (if it's not set it does nothing and won't affect your colleagues)