# ld: library not found

Tags: build, linker, ld

I'm trying to build a project that depends on SDL2 library. I've installed and linked it using homebrew:

```
> ls /usr/local/lib | grep SDL2
libSDL2-2.0.0.dylib
libSDL2.a
libSDL2.dylib
libSDL2_test.a
libSDL2main.a
```

I also added `/usr/local/lib` to my `/etc/paths` and `~/.bash_profile` as well:

```
> cat /etc/paths
/usr/local/lib
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

However, when I try to build the project, I still get this error:

```
error: linking with `cc` failed: exit code: 1
note: cc '-m64' '-L' (...) '-lSDL2'
ld: library not found for -lSDL2
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Why does it happen and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I fixed the issue by adding `/usr/local/lib` to my `$LIBRARY_PATH`:

For bash, in `~/.bash_profile`:

```
export LIBRARY_PATH="$LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib"
```

And for fish shell, in `~/.config/fish/config.fish`:

```
set -g -x LIBRARY_PATH $LIBRARY_PATH /usr/local/lib
```

Answer (score 1):

`/etc/paths` is for executable files, not shared libraries. Same with the `$PATH` environmental variable set in `.bash_profile`. These are the paths searched for programs when you type a command in the terminal.

What you need to do is change the linkers **link path**. See the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12582987/clang-linker-does-not-look-into-ld-library-path) for details on how to set up the link path.

Comment: The answer to the linked question suggests changing the call to the linked, but I don't call it myself; rather, it is called automatically by other tools used to compiled the project. Can I add library path globally?