# dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib, php-fpm, php5.6

Tags: php, macos, openssl, homebrew, php-5.6

I am using a **php5.6** on my **Mac OS**, and *php-fpm* throws an issue:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/php@5.6/sbin/php-fpm
  Reason: image not found
```

Now i have latest OpenSSL version installed. And cannot downgrade it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26430432/ld-library-not-found this might help you.

Comment: PHP 5.6 is no longer supported. Please don't use it.

Comment: @Dharman , but how to be with legacy projects?)

Comment: Is this a legacy project? Why has it stopped working now? If you are trying to fix a legacy project it would be worth mentioning this in the question.

Comment: I develop it on my local machine with the same environment. It is stoped to work because Homebrew updated version of OpenSSL. @Dharman

Comment: Running `brew update && brew upgrade` was enough for me 

Comment: @MarlonBarcarol , When that’s was enough? This command updates all formularies to the latest versions. But I need to install older one. Because ***php@5.6*** doesn’t support OpenSSL >= 1.0.1 version.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To solve this problem you need:

1. Go to https://www.openssl.org/source/old/ and download version you need
2. Open downloaded archive and then open terminal there
3. Run `$ make clean`, `$ ./Configure darwin64-x86_64-cc -shared`, `$ make`, `$ make install`
4. Put **libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib** and **libssl.1.0.0.dylib** to the `/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/lib/`

And now it works (For me)!

Comment: Does this mean you now have both OpenSSL 1.1 and OpenSSL 1.0 installed ?

Comment: @PepijnOlivier , it means that I have needed files for working php 5.6, but by default my system use the latest version. Do you understand? I just compiled needed files and put them to needed path)

Comment: Alright, thanks! I can confirm this works for PHP 5.6 and 7.0, which both depend on `libcrypto 1.0.0`.

Comment: @PepijnOlivier , 

Comment: got and error like this when running "make install"

```cms.pod around line 474: Expected text after =item, not a number
POD document had syntax errors at /usr/bin/pod2man5.18 line 72.
make: *** [install_docs] Error 255```

anyonw experienced something like mine?

Comment: @imansyaefulloh what system did you run it on? Maybe you need something else than darvin64...

Answer (score 0):

I have a good news. **eXolnet** published a patch for php@5.6 witch fixes openssl bug. [All instructions here](https://github.com/eXolnet/homebrew-deprecated/pull/25)

Answer (score 0):

The perfect solution in macOS Catalina with PHP 7.2, this line:

```
brew uninstall openssl; brew uninstall openssl; brew install https://github.com/tebelorg/Tump/releases/download/v1.0.0/openssl.rb
```

Fuente:

https://github.com/kelaberetiv/TagUI/issues/86#issue-303370944

Answer (score 0):

For me following worked (macOS Catalina with PHP 7.1)

```
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies openssl
brew install https://github.com/tebelorg/Tump/releases/download/v1.0.0/openssl.rb
```