# Vim and Environment Modules: compilation via :make does not know boost

Tags: cmake, vim, linker, environment-modules

My C++ project uses [CMake](http://www.cmake.org) for creating makefiles for compilaton and external libraries from [boost](http://www.boost.org). My editor of choice is [vim](http://www.vim.org).
Running `$ make` in the command line works but `:make` in vim has problems at the linking stage and returns:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_system
```

However, I also use `:make install` to place my project in [`$HOME/usr/stow/<prog>`](https://www.gnu.org/software/stow/) where I test and use the program. Therefore I am looking for a solution to make the linking stage successful.

Further details:

It is an [out-of-src build](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/FAQ#what-is-an-out-of-source-build) dir. Therefore I've configured [`makeprg`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27makeprg%27)

```
:set makeprg=make\ -C\ ../build/Release/
```

A more recent boost version is installed and made available on the system via [Environment Modules](http://modules.sourceforge.net/) which I rely on in my project. The newer boost version can be loaded via

```
$ module load boost
```

I have added this line to my `$HOME/.profile`, so that I don't have to call it each time I am compiling.

I have checked the question [(G)VIM uses a different $PATH than my system](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23637/gvim-uses-a-different-path-than-my-system) discussing Environment variables as used in vim.

**UPDATE:** The problem occurred only in gvim started from the window manager(gnome2) and not (g)vim started from the commandline/bash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it works at the command line, but not in vim, see what's different in your environment

```
:!env | sort > env-vim
```

then

```
$ env | sort | diff env-vim -
```

It's likely something is setting the LD_LIBRARY_PATH to include a non-standard directory for your boost libraries and that's not showing up in the subshell environment of vim. Perhaps you're launching vim from a desktop icon rather than the command line? (vim / :make from the command line would be an interesting test if that's the case).

To get a variable into the vim subshell, add it to the ~/.vimrc

```
let $LD_LIBRARY_PATH="*your library path*"
```

*I would have commented rather than answered, but I haven't earned that ability, yet. Since it was asked yesterday I gave it shot.*

Comment: thanks for your answer. It was really helpful. Now I could figure it out. It was actually only gvim with linking problems and not vim in the commandline. Actually, I had to set the env variable `$LIBRARY_PATH`: `let $LIBRARY_PATH="/apps/boost/1_50_0/lib/:".$LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: Further information for someone with a similar problem, see following websites: [vim.wikia.com/EnvVar](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Environment_variables), [ld-library-path-vs-library-path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4250624/ld-library-path-vs-library-path) and [Re: gvim - environment/bashrc not loaded](http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/gvim-environment-bashrc-not-loaded-tp1179930p1179931.html)

Comment: Glad that worked for you.  Thanks for adding the pointer to the difference between LD_LIBRARY_PATH and LIBRARY_PATH