# Why ld can't find lboost_regex?

Tags: boost, ld, source-highlighting

I'm trying to compile [`GNU Source highlight`](http://www.gnu.org/software/src-highlite/) in my home directory.

I configured with a prefix and `--with-boost=/path/to/boost/root/dir/` and no errors were reported.

But when I try to build I got the following error:

```
$ make
 ... # lots of output
libtool: link: g++ -shared -nostdlib /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../lib64/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/crtbeginS.o  .libs/copyright.o .libs/reportbugs.o .libs/fileutil.o .libs/substfun.o .libs/stopwatch.o .libs/utils.o .libs/ioexception.o .libs/settings.o .libs/versions.o .libs/verbosity.o .libs/sourcehighlight.o .libs/styleparser.o .libs/stylescanner.o .libs/outlangdefparser.o .libs/stylecssparser.o .libs/stylecssscanner.o .libs/outlangdefscanner.o .libs/debuglistener.o .libs/langmap.o .libs/stylefileparser.o .libs/langelem.o .libs/statelangelem.o .libs/langelems.o .libs/statestartlangelem.o .libs/stringlistlangelem.o .libs/delimitedlangelem.o .libs/langelemsprinter.o .libs/namedsubexpslangelem.o .libs/stringdef.o .libs/highlightrule.o .libs/highlighttoken.o .libs/highlightstate.o .libs/highlightrulefactory.o .libs/highlightstateprinter.o .libs/sourcehighlighter.o .libs/sourcefilehighlighter.o .libs/linenumgenerator.o .libs/lineranges.o .libs/regexranges.o .libs/formatter.o .libs/formattermanager.o .libs/textstyle.o .libs/textstyleformatter.o .libs/bufferedoutput.o .libs/preformatter.o .libs/wordtokenizer.o .libs/ctagscollector.o .libs/readtags.o .libs/ctagsformatter.o .libs/srcuntabifier.o .libs/textstyleformatterfactory.o .libs/docgenerator.o .libs/doctemplate.o .libs/chartranslator.o .libs/textstylebuilder.o .libs/fileinfo.o .libs/ctagsmanager.o .libs/regexhighlightrule.o .libs/regexrulefactory.o .libs/regexpreprocessor.o .libs/highlightstatebuilder.o .libs/highlightbuilderexception.o .libs/langdefmanager.o .libs/langdefparser.o .libs/langdefscanner.o .libs/languageinfer.o .libs/parserexception.o .libs/stringtable.o .libs/vardefinitions.o .libs/sourcehighlightutils.o .libs/yywrap.o  -Wl,--whole-archive ../../gl/.libs/libgnu.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive  -lboost_regex -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../lib64 -L/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/../lib64 -lstdc++ -lm -lc -lgcc_s /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/crtendS.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../lib64/crtn.o    -Wl,-soname -Wl,libsource-highlight.so.1 -o .libs/libsource-highlight.so.1.1.0
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_regex
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Note that, I have Boost loaded in my environment, in fact:

```
$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH 
/path/to/boost/root/dir/lib:/other/path/lib
```

and `ls` shows that `/path/to/boost/root/dir/lib/libboost_regex.so` exists and is a symbolic link to `libboost_regex.so.1.47.0`

How is this possible? How can I solve it?

Comment: Is this help? -> http://www.gnu.org/software/src-highlite/source-highlight.html#Tips-on-installing-Boost-Regex-library

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At linking time, the correct environment variable to use to define the path where to find the libraries is `LIBRARY_PATH`, not `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. The former is equivalent to specifying `-L` in the `gcc` arguments, while the latter is used at runtime, like `PATH`, to find the binary executables. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4250624/ld-library-path-vs-library-path) for more information.