# How to add .h and .o files to gcc

Tags: c, gcc, header-files, object-files

I'm trying to figure out how to add header and object files to the standard library so that I can use my custom files as easy as the standard library.

Currently I have to type the path to the header file in the .c file and then link the object file path when compiling.

I would like to just be able to add:

```
#include <mystdlib.h>
```

and not worry about linking the object file like I do when I reference the stdio.h header file.

I have searched around, but I fear I'm not using the proper terminology as I don't seem to find the results I need.  Am I the first to want to do this, or it is just impossible, and therefore people don't even try?

Comment: If your header file is in the same project folder as the `.c` file you can use: `#include "mystdlib.h"`

Comment: If the header is NOT in a standard location, and not in your current directory, then use the "-I" argument to specify the directory that contains it.  for example:  `gcc -I/home/mysql/include xx.c -o xx`

Comment: Using a tool like http://www.gnu.org/software/make/ will greatly simplify your build process. Generally you don't want to manually invoke gcc because compiling and linking everything in non-trivial projects is both time consuming and error prone.

Comment: @CaptainMurphy Proper makefiles are often notoriously hard to get right. And if they're going to use `Make` and not something like cmake or automake (or whatever your favorite build system is), they still need to know the basics (or just spend a day reading `info gcc`).

Comment: If the header is in the same directory as your source file you can use `#include "header.h"` and you don't need to use `-I` to tell the compiler where to find it. If it's not in the same directory use a makefile (I disagree with the comment above, simple makefiles are very simple, e.g. as little as `CPPFLAGS = -I ~/path/to/headers` is a valid makefile)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gcc` uses environment variables `C_INCLUDE_PATH` and `LIBRARY_PATH` to look for header and library files. Setting them somewhere (eg., your `bash_profile)` should achieve what you describe:

```
export C_INCLUDE_PATH="$HOME/include"
export LIBRARY_PATH="$HOME/lib"
```

Alternatively, the `-I` and `-L` flags add directories to the list of directories to be searched for header files and library files, respectively.

*edit:* As noted by @ChrisStratton below, the library name or object file needs to be explicitly specified. AFAIK, there is no way to make gcc always link against a library (like with `libc`).

**sources:**

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Environment-Variables.html
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html

Comment: This will take care of the searching, but the library name or object file implementing the functionality would still have to be explicitly specified.

Comment: An alternative to exporting LIBRARY_PATH allowing the executable to load your custom lib, you can also specify `rpath` which will be included in the executable itself (e.g. `-Wl,-rpath=/path/to/your/lib`) Note, this means that your library must be in the same place on other systems for your executable to run on other boxes.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Thanks! I've incorporated your comment to the answer. I'm curious if it's possible to make gcc automatically link against something.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Good point. For dynamic libs `rpath` can be used in lieu of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, but `LIBRARY_PATH` _must_ be set either way (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4250624/ld-library-path-vs-library-path)

Comment: @MBlanc, I don't know what you mean about `LIBRARY_PATH` _must_ be set ... most people use `-L` and don't use `LIBRARY_PATH` at all.