# Linking SDL2 with gcc

Tags: c, gcc, linker, sdl-2

After having downloaded the development library for SDL2 and attempting to link it with the -lSDL2 command in gcc, I am told that the library can not be found. Is there a specific directory i should place the framework in ? Or can I specify the directory in the command line so it knows where to link it from?

Comment: Shouldn't it be in lower-cases, like `-lsdl2` or alike?

Comment: I don't think so but possibly thanks for the input.

Comment: I downvoted the question because OP does not bother to comment on the answers though he was on multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

You use the `-l` (lower-case L) to tell the linker to link with a specific library.

You use the `-L` option to tell the linker about which folders to search for libraries.

So if you have install SDL2 in a non-standard location, use the `-L` option to specify where the library is installed, just like you use the `-I` (capital i) to specify where headers are for the preprocessor to find them.

Answer (score 0):

If you have not placed it within one of the standard paths where to search for libraries, you should set and export a correctly defined `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`/`LIBRARY_PATH` variable.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4250624/ld-library-path-vs-library-path) discussion contains enough information.