# import sklearn error with anaconda python 3.52

Tags: python, macos, gcc, scikit-learn

Fresh install of anaconda python3 onto secondary hard drive of mac running mavericks.

```
import sklearn
```

gives

```
Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /Volumes/SecondHD/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/isolve/_iterative.so
  Reason: image not found
```

gcc was installed with home-brew and exists.

```
which gcc
```

gives

```
/usr/bin/gcc
```

In /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/6.1.0/lib/gcc/6 I can find libgcc_s.1.dylib so I know it's there even tho it was not symlinked in /usr/local/lib.

Rather than adding more symlinks to /usr/local/lib from all the libraries in Cellar, I instead added the location of the libraries to the search path.

In my ~.profile I have

```
export LIBRARY_PATH="$LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib"
export LIBRARY_PATH="$LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/6.1.0/lib/gcc/6"
```

But that does not work. However, the error goes away if I add this line to my .profile

```
export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/6.1.0/lib/gcc/6
```

My understanding from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4250624/ld-library-path-vs-library-path) post is that LIBRARY_PATH is a list of places a compiler (like gcc) will look for libraries when it is linking code. But in Mac OSX, DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH and DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH contain a list of places any program will search for a shared library when it runs.

So if sklearn wants a gcc library, that would mean some compilation (and linking) will happen. Why is this line not sufficient

```
export LIBRARY_PATH="$LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/6.1.0/lib/gcc/6"
```

and why is DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH or DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH needed?

Comment: do you have a libgcc in your environment?

Comment: what do you mean 'environment'? I set the environment variable export LIBRARY_PATH="$LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/6.1.0/lib/gcc/6" In that folder is libgcc

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. What I did was creating symbolic links from my cellar folder of gcc to /usr/local/lib.

1. look for the right path of you gcc
2. `ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/X.X.X/lib/gcc/6/* /usr/local/lib`

Comment: Small comment - I don't have gcc through homebrew, but something about upgrading to Sierra broke some things in my installations; I just had to run `ln -s /usr/local/lib/gcc/6/lib* /usr/local/lib/` and now things work. Thanks!