# g++: restbed error: ld returned 1 exit status in ubuntu that only -L option solved it

Tags: c++, ubuntu, linker, restbed

## My Problem

I want to use [restbed](https://github.com/Corvusoft/restbed) on my C++ project, and I follow the instruction to install it on my ubuntu machine. I installed the include file to `/usr/local/include` and library file to `/usr/local/library`.

Problem is:

```
@ubuntu:~/test$ g++ test.cpp -o test -lrestbed -std=c++11
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lrestbed
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It means ubuntu knows where my include files are, but has no idea where the link files are or link files are damaged. And things are getting weird, see last section.

## What I've done

I have searched many solutions for this problem, including [this](https://lonesysadmin.net/2013/02/22/error-while-loading-shared-libraries-cannot-open-shared-object-file/). I follow the guild and added `/usr/local/lib` and `/usr/local/library` to `/etc/ld.so.conf`, so basically my linker knows where to find link files.

```
@ubuntu:~/test$ cat /etc/ld.so.conf
include /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf
/usr/loacl/lib
/usr/local/library
```

And when I g++ again I failed, same error message. I've even tried `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/library"`, and I also ran `sudo ldconfig` but still no luck.

## Weird Solution

So I found that I can compile it with this command:

```
g++ -L /usr/local/library test.cpp -o test -lrestbed -std=c++11
```

And everything works like charm. So my link files are fine, and I am confused ... why the system PATH is not working? And how do I solve this? (I don't want to type the long path every time and it gets verbose when I use more third-party libraries).

**My system:**

`ubuntu 16.04 LTS` running on parallel desktop

`g++` (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609

Comment: `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is used a runtime. `LIBRARY_PATH` at link time. Consider using a Makefile where you specify the `-L` options though. Then you only type `make`. http://stackoverflow.com/a/4250666/1116364

Comment: @DanielJour Thanks a lot, your answer reminds me my searching key words are wrong. Problem solved when I typed in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH vs LIBRARY_PATH `.