# How to build c++ with all dependencies to run on another machine

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I wrote c++ code that in including some libraries that I included using `-l` option. The code is right on my machine but I want finally run this code on another machine named B. I built it on my machine using `c++11` and `GNU GCC Compiler` and attempt to run it on machine B but it errors :

`error while loading shared libraries: libcppkafka.so.0.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

How can I build c++ code with all dependencies to disappear this error?

**note**: `libcppkafka.so.0.1` is in my machine in path `/usr/local/lib`

**note**: I use `codeblock` IDE, so I appreciate that if solution will be codeblock compatible

**note**: Both machines are ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Are you on Linux ? Does both machine have the same CPU architecture ? What compiler and option are you using ?

Comment: You have to have shared libraries in every machine you want to run your code. Otherwise, build it static only.

Comment: @Clonk `GNU GCC compiler and ubuntu 16.04`

Comment: @miradham How can I build it statically?

Comment: @soheil That depends on the library. If you can compile and install a static version you can löink it statically into you program.

Comment: If the .so file is in your machine, it may simply be that your executable does not know the path of the library. Try setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH to the location of your so files.

Comment: @Clonk I should set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in my machine or machine B (that I want run on)?

Comment: LD_LIBRARY_PATH is searched at runtime so you should set it on your machine B. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4250624/ld-library-path-vs-library-path.

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve your goal you have 2 options.

1. You can copy your shared libraries(libcppkafka.so) with your executable and configure its location correctly.
2. Or you can avoid shared libraries by statically linking them to your program. For this you'll need to have static version of those libraries (`libcppkafka` in your case)

Answer (score 0):

Since both machines are running the same distribution and version (Ubuntu 16.04), you could find out on the first machine the installed and useful packages, and install these on the second machine.

You'll need to copy the non-packaged things, e.g. in (some part of) `/usr/local/lib`

You could consider making a real [`.deb` package](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deb_%28file_format%29) for your thing (but that is more work).

Notice that an IDE is just an IDE and don't compile anything (an IDE is running *external* compiler commands; your compiler is GCC invoked as `g++`). You should perhaps compile on the command line (and you could even make that some shell script, to run on the other machine).