# Wrong path searched when running c++ program

Tags: c++, gcc

Hi. I am using a machine remotely which has an g++ version too old to compile a c++ program. I installed gcc-5.4.0 using  http://luiarthur.github.io/gccinstall. The code complies but when running it I get the following error:

> ./run_with_config: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by ./run_with_config)
>   ./run_with_config: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version`CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by ./run_with_config)
>   ./run_with_config: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.18' not found (required by ./run_with_config)
>   ./run_with_config: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version`CXXABI_1.3.5' not found (required by ./run_with_config)
>   ./run_with_config: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by ./run_with_config)

So the path that is searched

> /usr/lib64/

is the incorrect one. I am not sure what I would have to adjust so that the correct path is the one searched.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4250624/ld-library-path-vs-library-path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compile with `-static-libstdc++` flag (probably you'll need `-static-libgcc` as well) - that will include newer runtime library inside binary, so outdated `/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6` library would not be used.