# g++ unable to locate libs

Tags: c++, c, g++, ld

I'm compiling my code using `g++ -L/lib64 -I /git/src  ...` but I get

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lm
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
```

I checked my /lib64/ and found that these libs are actually present

```
/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 -> libstdc++.so.6.0.19
/usr/lib64/libm.so -> ../../lib64/libm.so.6
/usr/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 -> libgcc_s-4.8.5-20150702.so.1
/usr/lib64/libc.so.6 -> libc-2.17.so
```

When I try `ld -lc --verbose` this too fails. All the libs are present in `/lib64` and the path is included still g++ fails to locate them. Any Idea what is going on ?

Comment: You're missing some `.so` symlinks. Without identifying your Linux distribution, no further help can be given, but you need to install the appropriate development package for your Linux distribution, that contain the required symlinks.

Comment: `CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core)` I have this in `/etc/redhat-releases.` I also changed `/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 -> libstdc++.so.6.0.19 ` to `/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so -> libstdc++.so.6.0.19.` the `ld -lstdc++ --verbose` worked. but g++ still reported the issue listing this pkg along with others

Comment: What development pkg should I install/check ?

Comment: Start with libstdc++-devel, glibc-devel, and gcc-c++

Comment: I tried yum install pkg name and got this ` Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Package gcc-c++-4.8.5-28.el7_5.1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do` . I also did [https://access.redhat.com/discussions/1262603#comment-867063] groupinstall Development tools does show up now. I still have same issue

Comment: @Raj Have you tried creating symlinks to the libraries you wish to link? I ran into this problem a few months back. I was left with two options, one being to just build the libraries from source and link that way OR to create symlinks and it would work without a problem.

Comment: One more thing, assigning [LD_LIBRARY_PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4250624/ld-library-path-vs-library-path) may also resolve your issue if you haven't already done so.

Comment: @Raj What does `rpm -qVa` show? This command will attempt to verify that the required files are actually installed.

Comment: @GKE I created all the missing symlinks. Still the same issue. Florian it gave me a bunch of missing files

Comment: There was an -Bstatic option with .a file instead .so file for dynamic loading. I removed -Bstatic option as I wanted to load .so file. This fixed the issue