# CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH without any effect

Tags: cmake, rpath

I would like to automatically add the path of libraries at link time to RPATH. After reading a bit I thought `CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH` should do the job. Unfortunatly, the following MWE does not do the job:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)

cmake_policy(SET CMP0060 NEW)
set(CMAKE_SKIP_BUILD_RPATH  FALSE)
# set(CMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH TRUE)
# set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib")
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH TRUE)

find_package(Boost COMPONENTS serialization REQUIRED)
# Setting CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH explicitly works
# set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "${CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH};${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS}")

add_executable(app main.cxx)

target_include_directories( app
    PUBLIC ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})

target_link_libraries( app
    PUBLIC Boost::serialization)

install(TARGETS app DESTINATION bin)
```

The output of `readelf -d install/bin/app` for the example above shows the dependencies but no RPATH:

```
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libboost_serialization.so.1.65.1]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libstdc++.so.6]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libm.so.6]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libgcc_s.so.1]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
```

The commented lines is some stuff that I tried so far. Setting `CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH` explicitly works. But setting `CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH` seems to have no effect. This is the case for both binaries, the build and the installed one.

Do I misunderstand what `CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH` is doing or can someone spot the mistake?
CMake 3.13, CentOS 7

Answer (score 4):

I still do not understand exactly whats going on but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4250624/ld-library-path-vs-library-path) and [here](https://github.com/STEllAR-GROUP/hpx/issues/2396) I found the hint that the environment variable `LIBRARY_PATH` (probably also `CPATH` and `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH`) influences which directories are added to RPATH if `CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH` is set. Those variables were set in my case by easybuild.  My guess is directories provided in `LIBRARY_PATH` at compile/link time are not added to `RPATH`. Unsetting `LIBRARY_PATH` solved my problem.