# Meson: how to make find_library() works with an unusual path?

Tags: meson-build

For my [Meson](https://mesonbuild.com/Reference-manual.html#find_library) project I have a dependency that is in an "unusual" place:

```
/opt/MyDependence/lib/libmyLib.so
/opt/MyDependence/include/myLib.hpp
```

My meson file is:

```
project('Test', ['cpp'])

cpp = meson.get_compiler('cpp')
myLib_dep = cpp.find_library('myLib', required: true)
```

Obviously Meson cannot find the library

```
Meson.build:5:0: ERROR: C++ library 'myLib' not found
```

The problem is that I do not know the "canonical" way to add extra search paths so that Meson can found my lib. Any idea?

---

**update:** please note that even if I use:

```
meson --libdir=/opt/MyDepedence/lib build
```

I get this error message:

```
meson.build:1:0: ERROR: The value of the 'libdir' option is '/opt/MyDepedence/lib' which must be a subdir of the prefix '/usr/local'.
Note that if you pass a relative path, it is assumed to be a subdir of prefix.
```

Comment: check my update regarding --libdir

Comment: @pmod thank you for the clarification

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`find_library` now has an optional argument `dirs` (since 0.53.0) that indicates an extra list of absolute paths where to look for program names.

```
cpp = meson.get_compiler('cpp')
myLib_dep = cpp.find_library('myLib', dirs: '/opt/MyDepedence/lib', required: true)
```

Answer (score 6):

I finally got a solution, one must use `LIBRARY_PATH`

```
export LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/MyDepedence/lib
meson build
```

**Note:** attention this is not `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, see [there](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4250624/2001017) for the difference

Also read this [Meson/issues/217](https://github.com/mesonbuild/meson/issues/217) . For Windows, the `LIBRARY_PATH` equivalent seems to be `LIBPATH` (but I was not able to check as I only run under Linux).

---

An alternative is to "manually" define a new dependence. In your Meson project:

```
project('Test, ['cpp'])

myLib_dep = declare_dependency(link_args : ['-L/opt/MyDependence/lib', '-lmyLib'],
                               include_directories : ['/opt/MyDependence/include'])


exe1 = executable('main', ['main.cpp'], dependencies : [myLib_dep])
```

A refinement that could be done is to store this "manual" setting into [meson_options.txt](https://mesonbuild.com/Build-options.html).

---

Note: I finally answered my question, but I am still open to better solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Standard way to solve this is to use [pkg-config](https://people.freedesktop.org/~dbn/pkg-config-guide.html). In short, library installation procedure should include stage where special "*mylib.pc*" file is generated (from scratch, or typically from template "*mylib.pc.in*" - search in the internet, there are lots of examples). Then these small key-value files which has info on include/library dirs, dependencies, etc are installed to some known location, typically */usr/lib/pkgconfig/*. Meson naturally runs pkg-config under the hood and finds your library when you have something like this

```
mylib_dep = dependency('mylib', required: true)
```

in your *meson.build*.

**Update**

Regarding *libdir* meson option error, you can try add option *prefix* as well:

```
meson --prefix=/opt/MyDepedence --libdir=lib build
```

Note also that with this command line you actually call implicitly **setup** command (there is no command **build**, since you will build with ninja) and *build* is a build directory that will be created using your options. Check [this](https://mesonbuild.com/Running-Meson.html). That is why it is more visible to write:

```
meson setup build_dir --prefix=/opt/MyDepedence --libdir=lib
```

Comment: Thanks, just wanted to add about "unusual path", sometimes you'd even want to install mylib.pc to unusual location and in this case adjusting for PKG_CONFIG_PATH is needed (https://askubuntu.com/questions/210210/pkg-config-path-environment-variable)