# Selecting a Meson dependency as another Meson project

Tags: gnome, meson-build

I am trying to build [gedit](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gedit) and [gedit-plugins](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gedit-plugins) using Meson on Fedora 34. Here I am using the `fedora:34` container as the environment.

First I build gedit and install it to `/opt`, which works fine.

```sh
sudo dnf install meson ninja-build git
sudo dnf install 'dnf-command(builddep)'
sudo dnf builddep gedit
git clone https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gedit.git
cd gedit
mkdir build && cd build
meson --prefix /opt
ninja
sudo ninja install
cd ..
```

Now I want to build gedit-plugins and use the previous built gedit as a dependency.

```sh
git clone https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gedit-plugins.git
cd gedit-plugins
mkdir build && cd build
meson --prefix /opt
```

However, the last `meson --prefix /opt` command fails:

```
Run-time dependency gedit found: NO (tried pkgconfig)

../meson.build:29:0: ERROR: Dependency "gedit" not found, tried pkgconfig

A full log can be found at /gedit-plugins/build/meson-logs/meson-log.txt
```

I know that if I install `gedit-devel`, then this dependency can be solved by providing header files in `/usr/include/gedit-40.0/gedit/`. However, I would like meson to find header files in `/opt/include/gedit-40.0/gedit/` automatically. How can I achieve this?

I tried `LIBRARY_PATH=/opt meson --prefix /opt` and `LIBRARY_PATH=/gedit/build meson --prefix /opt`, but neither work.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59769986/8925535)

Answer (score 1):

In meson.build like 29 checks the dependency via `gedit_dep = dependency('gedit', version: '>= 40.0')`. You can add your custom folder to look by editing the line as `gedit_dep = dependency('gedit', version: '>= 40.0', dirs: '/opt')`.

This is because you have installed the libraries and dependency of gedit in `/opt`

Answer (score 0):

Try using Meson [compiler.find_library()](https://mesonbuild.com/Reference-manual_returned_compiler.html#compilerfind_library).

Use:

- `dir` argument to specify directories to search in for binary
- `has_headers` and `header_include_directories` to specify which headers are required and where to search for them