# Libtorch c++ meson dependency

Tags: c++, pytorch, meson-build, libtorch

i am currently trying to use Pytorch in my C++ program by including & linking libtorch into the project. Build system is meson where i have the following top-level *meson.build* file `torch_dep = dependency('torch')`

which then is used in my sub-level *meson.build*:

```
main = executable(
      name,
      [
        'PytorchModel.cpp',
      ],
      include_directories : [
        project_incdir,
      ]
      install : true,
      dependencies : [
        torch_dep,
    ]
```

When building i get the error:

*meson.build:12:0: ERROR: Dependency "torch" not found, tried pkgconfig and cmake*

I also checked pkg-config list and libtorch is not in there. How can i make this link?
Another thing i tried is to download/unzip libtorch manually and move it to */usr/include/*. Still it is not recognized.
Also tried `build_rpath : "/usr/include/libtorch"` in the executable to use the manual path. Still not working.

My goal in the end is to use `#include <torch/script.h>` in my .cpp file.

I am very unexperienced with meson, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62132772/8925535)

Comment: Thanks @droptop. That seems to work for finding the library, but somehow it does not include the libtorch inside the build so i still get  fatal error: torch/script.h: No such file or directory.
Any clue how to link my file with the library?

Comment: You'll have to add `script.h`'s directory to the `include_directories` list

Comment: Do you have the devel package installed? And if you do, have you tried `dependency('Torch')`. It looks like Torch only has cmake files, and those can be case sensitive.