# How can I specify library path when using Meson?

Tags: cmake, meson-build

I'm trying to build a c++ project with Meson.

The thing is, I have some libraries under `/opt/conda`
but can't figure out how to link the project when running `meson build`.
It seems to be only searching through `/usr/lib` directory.

As far as I understood, `meson` uses `cmake` and `pkg-config` to look for libraries.
Then would setting something like `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` be a feasible solution? and if so, how can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I see two possible approaches to solve your problem.

- the first solution uses `LIBRARY_PATH`, which is different from `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` as explained later.
- the second solution uses a modified meson file to directly pass options to the linker. Optionally, it also uses `rpath` that eliminates the need to modify `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` afterward.

  1. **First solution**

When building your project the linker use `LIBRARY_PATH` (and not  `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`)

> `LIBRARY_PATH` is used by gcc before compilation to search directories
>   containing static and shared libraries that **need to be linked to your
>   program.**
>
> `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is used by your program to search directories
>   containing shared libraries **after it has been successfully compiled
>   and linked.**

**further details**: [LD_LIBRARY_PATH vs LIBRARY_PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4250624/2001017)

Maybe you can try

```
export LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/conda/:$LIBRARY_PATH
```

before running meson to build your project.

2. **Second solution**

Modifying your meson file and use `rpath` (optional)

An alternative to the previous first solution is to directly modify your Meson file to pass some options to the **linker**.

Here is something I used in the past you can easily adapt to your problem:

```
#
# blaspp
#
blaspp_lib = 'blaspp'
blaspp_lib_dir = '/opt/slate/lib'
blaspp_header_dir = '/opt/slate/include'

blaspp_dep = declare_dependency(
    link_args : ['-L' + blaspp_lib_dir, '-l' + blaspp_lib],
    include_directories : include_directories(blaspp_header_dir))

executable('test_blaspp',
       'test_blaspp.cpp',
       build_rpath : blaspp_lib_dir,
       install_rpath : blaspp_lib_dir,
       dependencies : [blaspp_dep])
```

- **declare_dependency(...)** defines options to pass to the **linker** (this replaces the need to define `LIBRARY_PATH` in the first solution)
- **executable(...)** defines `rpath`. This is an optional step that embeds the extra library path information directly into the executable. If you use this, you will not have to modify the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` when running your executable.

**Further details:** https://amir.rachum.com/blog/2016/09/17/shared-libraries/ (have a look at the "rpath and runpath" section) and see wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rpath

Comment: Thanks! The second solution did the trick. Turns out, I had to modify the `meson.build` file anyway because the `dependency()` function that the given `meson.build` file was using doesn't seem to follow the `LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I will try to have a look at the LIBRARY_PATH solution

Comment: The second solution worked for me as well. How do you use 'build_rpath' with several libs folders ?  what needs to be change in the above solution for several libs and libs folders ?

Comment: @yehudahs, thanks for the feedback. Did you try build_rpath : 'dir_1;dir_2;dir_3'. According to meson doc build_rpath is  'a string to add to target's rpath definition'. Not sure it works, that's my suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the [documentation](https://mesonbuild.com/Mixing-build-systems.html) correctly, you could use different / others build system as subproject, and it doesn't seem basing on cmake.
You should be able to define `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` in a CMakeList.txt of a cmake project, and access the generated library within `meson` context:
in your cmake subproject:

```
add_library(cm_lib SHARED ${SOURCES})
```

in your meson:

```
cmake = import('cmake')

# Configure the CMake project
sub_proj = cmake.subproject('libsimple_cmake')

# Fetch the dependency object
cm_lib = sub_proj.dependency('cm_lib')

executable(exe1, ['sources'], dependencies: [cm_lib])
```

if you only want to propagate any specific library to `meson`, than it looks like you'll need to [bundle those third party library](https://mesonbuild.com/Subprojects.html), or using [built-in options](https://mesonbuild.com/Builtin-options.html).

**But first of all**: Have you check, either `/opt/conda` is in your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` ?

Comment: Thanks @dboy Yes I do have `/opt/conda/lib` in my `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` but it didn't really help when configuring build environment. The project I was trying to build was based on GStreamer and most part of their `meson.build` file was given. I just wanted to include the libraries so reconfiguring it to `cmake` subproject wasn't a solution I was looking for. But the bundling third party library seems feasible so I'll look into it.

Answer (score 2):

Surprised no one mentioned it but this is how it is done from within meson.

```
CXX = meson.get_compiler('cpp')
libs_you_need_to_link = ['lib_a', 'lib_b', 'lib_c']
deps = []
foreach lib_name : libs_you_need_to_link 
    deps += CXX.find_library(lib_name, dirs : ['/opt/conda', '/other/path'])
endforeach
```