# Find Third-Party Libraries with Cygwin

Tags: cygwin

I started using Cygwin to build my projects, but I don't know how to set it up to find my third party libraries.
For example, I placed my directx-headers where they can be found in the system path, but Cygwin, does not seem to search the system path variable.

How can I setup Cygwin to find libraries outside its container in a third party folder, or in my system path on a Windows OS?

Comment: what program are you trying to build and with which tool ? You can always add any specific directory to the search , but the PATH is not the methode to use

Comment: How do I add a specific directory to the search? I would prefer that actually, since I believe Cygwin packages could conflict with other libraries.

Comment: you need to provide more info. What tools are you using ?

Comment: I'm on a Windows pc, using Cygwin with all the required packages, trying to build mesa from source. Meson looks for python, cmake, and uses gcc, from what I gathered from the build so far. All of these are available in Cygwin. I'll edit the OP to show this.

Comment: Mesa is already built as Cygwin package, see https://cygwin.com/packages/summary/mesa-src.html . The best way to replicate the build is to download the cygwin source package and build using the `cygport` tool. But it seems you are not building for Cygwin but for Mingw

Comment: I'm new to these tools, so I don't understand what you mean. What do you mean by replicate the build, and why is that something I want to do? What am I building? What do you mean by building for Mingw and not Cygwin? I thought I was just building the libraries for mesa, so that i can use them, as they are required by a tool i want to use. Thanks for the link. I did not know it was so readily available. I was searching for the egl libraries and was coming up empty - except from building the source.

Comment: You said I can always add any specific directory to the search. can you show me how to do that? that was the purpose of the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe **the answer is with using PKG_CONFIG_PATH**, as defined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61058722/how-can-i-specify-library-path-when-using-meson), and in the answer given [here](https://superuser.com/questions/586285/pkg-config-doesnt-find-package-file-when-folder-is-listed-in-pkg-config-path).

I also found this on the github page of the directx-headers...

> Pkg-config: Use Meson to build this project, and the resulting
> installed package can be found via pkg-config.

Found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61058722/how-can-i-specify-library-path-when-using-meson) answer, also useful.

Finally, I found [this](http://www.es.ele.tue.nl/%7Eljozwiak/education/5JJ70p/blocks/1/cygwin.html), which was useful, and provided the information I wanted to know regarding Cygwin searching the PATH.

**Significantly Edited [SOLVED]** -
**The solution** : ***[Guide to pkg-config](https://people.freedesktop.org/%7Edbn/pkg-config-guide.html)***

> On a typical Unix system, it will search in the directories
> /usr/lib/pkgconfig and /usr/share/pkgconfig. This will usually cover
> system installed modules. However, **some local modules may be installed
> in a different prefix such as /usr/local. In that case, it's necessary
> to prepend the search path so that pkg-config can locate the .pc
> files**.

```
$ pkg-config --modversion hello
```

> Package hello was not found in the pkg-config search path.  Perhaps
> you should add the directory containing `hello.pc' to the
> PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable  No package 'hello' found

```
$ export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig 
$ pkg-config --modversion hello
```

> 1.0.0

What was required is using **export VAR=value**(or path-to-directory)
After this, the path ***will*** be found successfully.

So to find Third-Party libraries etc., simply use the export variable command.

Answer (score 0):

as reported on Meson manual

https://mesonbuild.com/Commands.html

```
$ meson configure [-h] [--prefix PREFIX] [--bindir BINDIR]
                  [--datadir DATADIR] [--includedir INCLUDEDIR]
                  [--infodir INFODIR] [--libdir LIBDIR]
                  [--libexecdir LIBEXECDIR] [--localedir LOCALEDIR]
 .....
```

you can use the `--includedir INCLUDEDIR`for the includes
and `--libdir LIBDIR` for the import libraries

Comment: Thanks. So rather than use configure, I can use setup as well, right? 
meson setup [-h] [--prefix PREFIX] [--bindir BINDIR] [--datadir DATADIR]
              [--includedir INCLUDEDIR] [--infodir INFODIR]
              [--libdir LIBDIR] [--libexecdir LIBEXECDIR]

Comment: it appears the commands --bindir --libdir etc., are all associated with where the libraries will be built, rather than where the libraries will be searched for during a build.
meson.build:21:0: ERROR: The value of the 'includedir' option is '/cygdrive/e/ThirdParty/Windows/DirectX/Include' which must be a subdir of the prefix '/cygdrive/c/dev/mesa'.
Note that if you pass a relative path, it is assumed to be a subdir of prefix.
Which is not what I want.