# MinGW32 can't configure sources: "undefined reference to `signal' and etc

Tags: gcc, windows-7, mingw, configure, undefined-reference

Last year I built some sources on MinGW without any problem. Now when I try to reconfigure this sources with another parameter I get (part of output of ./configure of libjansson-2.10 in config.log):

```
configure:3318: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:3340: gcc    conftest.c  >&5
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../crt2.o:(.text+0x34): 
undefined reference to `signal'
...
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../crt2.o:(.text+0x89): 
undefined reference to `_imp___iob'
...
```

and other undefined references. BUT if I make these old configured sources they are rebuilt successfully.

I uninstalled the old MinGW and downloaded a new one, checked all the dll, bin and dev related checkboxes, but still get the same error with different sources. I changed **PATH** to remove all links except **C:\MinGW\bin;C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin;**, and etc. but all the same. Is this a problem with PATH or pkg-config or something else?

**UPDATE:**
When I compile Hello world I get the same errors.

```
g++ -Wall -o2 -s -nodefaultlibs Hello.cpp -o Hello.exe
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: 
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../crt2.o:(.text+0x97): undefined reference to `signal'
```

Comment: Why do you have the `-nodefaultlibs` linker flag? That's probably why `signal()` is undefined.

Comment: No, -nodefaultlibs reduces the number of errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was in **LIBRARY_PATH** variable that stores this value:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\lib\x64;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um 
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\lib;
```

[LD_LIBRARY_PATH vs LIBRARY_PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4250624/ld-library-path-vs-library-path)

When I delete it and restart computer all of that undefined is gone.